# Get rid of Optional [] String?

Tags: java

Testing with streams on Stackoverflow API in Java

```
    public Optional<String> getShortestTitel() {
    // return the the shortest title
    return stream().map(Question::getTitle).min(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
}
```

my Output:

> Optional[Check instanceof in stream]

how can I get rid of the Optional[]?

Comment: How are you printing this output? Show us that code as well please.

Comment: The [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) provide for all sorts of methods to accomplish that. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Optional#orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) e.g.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

class Question {
    private String title;

    public Question(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        Question q1 = new Question("Hello");
        Question q2 = new Question("World");
        System.out.println(getShortestTitel(List.of(q1, q2)).orElseGet(() -> ""));
    }

    public static Optional<String> getShortestTitel(List<Question> list) {
        // return the the shortest title
        return list.stream().map(Question::getTitle).min(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
```

Comment: Why not `Optional#orElse`?

Comment: @iota - It depends on the requirement. `Optional#orElse` can be used if a static value is required.  Using `Optional#orElseGet`, any value can be generated dynamically.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash: *.orElseGet(() -> "")* ... There is a cost to allocating and invoking a lambda.  Do you mean to imply that it makes sense to use a lambda expression even for cases where values are simple and cheaply evaluated, such as an empty string?

Comment: @scottb - *Do you mean to imply that it makes sense to use a lambda expression even for cases where values are simple and cheaply evaluated, such as an empty string?* - No, I have mentioned that it depends on the requirement.